Is prometheus `sum` suspectible to doubling the actual value, as `increase` is?
I encountered a case where sum by query reported double the value it should have, and it seems to have corrected itself retrospectively when looking at it now (so the data looked different when looking at it relatively live, compared to looking at it now).
I've found some posts that hinted that some metrics may result in incorrect values, especially if they are working with low sample rate (we have 5 minutes set up) - increase in prometheus doubles values and sum_over_time gives double of the actual value.
Can the same problem occur with sum by? I don't see why it should, but I don't know much about prometheus to tell for sure. I am 99% certain that the program producing the metrics was not running twice or anything like that.
The query itself is really just sum by (...) (metric{ ... } offset -5m), no increase or any other function is present there.

Doubt sum might be a culprit here. If anything - offset with negative shift might. But without reproducible example, of course it's futile to guess.
